# Can i make ghost of HP UX11?

Tags: ghost

Is there any way to make ghost of HP UX11 on different server hardware???

Answer (score 1):

Here is a similar question with responses from the HP forums:

http://forums13.itrc.hp.com/service/forums/questionanswer.do?admit=109447627+1263630166226+28353475&threadId=731251

more info here:

http://docs.hp.com/en/B2355-90772/ch11s12.html